# How to get pixel values from Android Image

Tags: android, performance

I'm using the camera2 api to capture a burst of images. To ensure fastest capture speed, I am currently using yuv420888.

(jpeg results in approximately 3 fps capture while yuv results in approximately 30fps)

So what I'm asking is how can I access the yuv values for each pixel in the image.

i.e.

```
Image image = reader.AcquireNextImage();
Pixel pixel = image.getPixel(x,y);
pixel.y = ...
pixel.u = ...
pixel.v = ...
```

Also if another format would be faster please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `Image` class you will see the immediate answer is simply the `.getPlanes()` method.

Of course, for `YUV_420_888` this will yield three planes of YUV data which you will have to do a bit of work with in order to get the pixel value at any given location, because the U and V channels have been downsampled and may be interlaced in how they are stored in the `Image.Plane`s. But that is beyond the scope of this question.

Also, you are correct that YUV will be the fastest available output for your camera. JPEG require extra time for encoding which will slow down the pipeline output, and RAW are very large and take a lot of time to read out because they are so large. YUV (of whatever type) is the data format that most camera pipelines work in so it is the 'native' output, and thus the fastest.

Comment: Getting the pixel values ended up being quite easy, just had to realise that it was 8 bits and just read each byte in turn for y, u, and v planes.